# How to replace every value with a customized one inside this associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array

I am new to PHP. Sorry if this sounds simple.

I have this PHP associative array:

```
$X = array(
    'Model1' => '6',
    'Model2' => '5',
    'Model3' => '1'
);
```

I want to convert it to look like this:

```
$Y = array(
    'Model1' => 'prefix_Model1_postfix',
    'Model2' => 'prefix_Model2_postfix',
    'Model3' => 'prefix_Model3_postfix'
);
```

The value in each converted record is replaced with a prefix, then followed by the key, then followed by a postfix. How can this be done? Thank you very much. Is `foreach` a good start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easily with `foreach`:

```
$arr = array("Model1" => 6, "Model2" => 5, "Model3" => 1);
$prefix = "prefix_";
$postfix = "_postfix";

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
$arr[$key] = $prefix.$key.$postfix;
}

print_r($arr);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/134698)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($x, function($val,$key) use(&$x) { 
    $x[$key] = 'prefix_' . $key . '_postfix';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to do with built-in function and closures:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  'Model1' => '6',
  'Model2' => '5',
  'Model3' => '1',
);

$data = array_map(function($data){
  return "prefix_Model{$data}_postfix";
}, $data);


var_dump($data);

?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/134697)